# Projecting a set of lat/lon points that spans on multiple UTM zones into a single grid

Tags: python-3.x, latitude-longitude, coordinate-systems, map-projections

I'm working on a project where **I need to transpose a lot of geographic locations (given by their latitude/longitude)**, all of them in a relatively small region (the size of a country like Nederlands for instance), **into a grid** in order to run some clustering algorithms and other stuff on them.

**My current implementation** uses the [utm](https://pypi.org/project/utm/) and [geopy](https://pypi.org/project/geopy/) modules. It works like a charm for some instances (south korea is nicely centered on a single UTM zone), but **does not as soon as the points span on several distinct UTM zones** (which is the case of Nederlands).

I've been thinking of clumsy/inelegant methods to do so (like shifting all points' longitude of a couple of degrees to try and 'recenter' it, or trying to 'stick back' zones to each other), but then I've been searching a bit and I realized that there actually exists [many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_map_projections) coordinates system, and several python modules (pyproj, basemap, ...) that deal with them.
So I'd rather not reinvent the wheel, if you see what I mean, especially not reinvent a square one.

**I do not need a great accuracy**, a variation of 5% from the real distances is definitely acceptable for me. But what I need is to be able to transpose a region of earth (given bounds on latitude and longitude) into a single coherent grid.

I don't think performance would be an issue, since I have about 1 million points at most, and I'm not in a hurry (if it takes a couple of minutes to convert, so be it).

**What would you advice me ?**
I favor an out-of-the box solution rather than implementing myself a coords converter, and since the project is coded in Python3, sticking to the language would definitely be a plus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the solution Google Maps came up back in 2005, with, to solve these kind of constraints was creating what is called [Web Mercator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Mercator_projection), currently known by the [EPSG: 3857](https://epsg.io/3857).

> I do not need a great accuracy, a variation of 5% from the real
>   distances is definitely acceptable for me

In this case you can definitely use Web Mercator.

Possible implementation in Python:

```
import math

def merc_x(lon):
  r_major=6378137.000
  return r_major*math.radians(lon)

def merc_y(lat):
  if lat>89.5:lat=89.5
  if lat<-89.5:lat=-89.5
  r_major=6378137.000
  r_minor=6356752.3142
  temp=r_minor/r_major
  eccent=math.sqrt(1-temp**2)
  phi=math.radians(lat)
  sinphi=math.sin(phi)
  con=eccent*sinphi
  com=eccent/2
  con=((1.0-con)/(1.0+con))**com
  ts=math.tan((math.pi/2-phi)/2)/con
  y=0-r_major*math.log(ts)
  return y
```

Note that Web Mercator implementation is much simpler than, for example, UTM, so the performance will be much better.

Comment: Web mercator is precisely what I needed. As for the functions you wrote in the answer: copy pasted the functions, modified 4 lines of code, and it works like a charm. Thanks a lot :-)